# How to read a PNG file in bash in the same way I would in python

Tags: python, bash, base64, png

I am trying to emulate python code in a simple bash script to make a simple curl request. For the curl request, I need to 64bit encode the image. Right now I am doing that like so:

```
test=$( base64 outimage.png )
```

However, the output does not match the output of the python code I am trying to emulate:

```
out_image = Image.open('outimage.png')
temp_output = StringIO.StringIO()
out_image.save(temp_output, format='PNG')
temp_output.seek(0)
output_s = temp_output.read()
print output_s
print base64.b64encode(output_s)
```

I have figured out that `output_s` and `cat outimage.png` do not match, where `cat outimage.png` looks like:

```
"?PNG

IHDRdp?T IDATx^͝    ??eu?OuwUuW?=?>?,0

??/?D..."
```

and `output_s` looks like:

```
"\x89PNG\r\n\x1a\n\x00\x00\x00\rIHDR\x00\x00\x00d\x00\x00\x00d\x08\x06\x00\x00\x00p\xe2\x95T\x00\x00>uIDATx\x9c\xcd\xbdY\xb0d\xd9u\x9e\xf7\xed\xe1L9\xdd\xa9\xe6[\xd5\xdd\xd5#\xe6\xa1\t\x82\x94H\x91\xb2B\xb2\xc2a\xca\x0c\xdb\xa2e;B\x0f\..."
```

How do I get the `output_s` from outimage.png in bash?

Comment: How do you inspect the value of `output_s`? Your python code does not show it.

Comment: Yep! Sorry, probably should have added a print line there as well.

Comment: Please do and update your question (please also don't assume that the output will be identical to what you've already seen. Instead, rerun it and copy-paste the output)

Comment: Thanks! I updated to reflect what i just ran and the output still doesn't match (the same as what it was before).

Comment: Huh. When I take your code, add imports for `base64`, `Image` and `StringIO`, copy a png as `outimage.png` and run it using `python yourfile`, I get a binary garbage followed by a base64 dump. At no point do I get an escape hex sequence. What command/UI do you use to run this snippet?

Comment: Really? I am just running it in ipython.

Comment: That could explain the difference in the output formatting. Try without `ipython`, just with regular `python`

Comment: That's so weird! I get binary instead of hex if I just run it with python, Why would that be?

Comment: `ipython` is probably trying to be helpful by showing your binary output in a text based, visually unambiguous way

Answer (score 0):

`cat outimage.png` should never look like `output_s`, but `test` and `base64.b64encode(output_s)` are what you want to match, right?

There is a also utility called `uuencode` in `shartools` (yum install sharutils) which can encode files. `uudecode` goes backwards.

This will produce a plain-text file from a binary

```
uuencode /path/to/image.png image.png > image.uu
```

Comment: Thanks! Yes, `test` and `base64.b64encode(output_s)` are what I am trying to match. I'll try your suggestion.

Comment: `test=$( base64 image.uu )` also doesn't match the python output. Any other ideas for why they wouldn't be matching?

Comment: No need to `base64 image.uu`, it is already converted to ASCII

Comment: Ah! `test=$( cat image.uu)` returns `begin 644 image.png MB5!.1PT*&@H````-24A$4@```&0```!D"`8```!PXI54```@`$E$051X7LV= M"9BD977O3W5W5757[SW[/L,L,`S[OB^*$1=$#)LBFB@!]6HT1A*?>).;Q!OC M2@1Q#2...` and should be returning `iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAGQAAABkCAYAAABw4pVUAAA+dUlEQVR4n...`.

Comment: Sorry, I'm just very confused as to what these commands are returning an what format everything is in.